# Awk error message targeting a parentheses

Tags: awk

I'm running this awk command but i cant find why it keeps on telling me that is wrong, all variables are instantiated (i have replaced them with string here to show you the error, but the error is the same), braces are all properly closed, any advice?

```
 key=$(echo "hello,there" | awk -F"," -v index=2 '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ $index) print i}')
```

I'm not the perfect awk user, but i really cant spot the issue here
Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`index` is a built-in function (keyword) so you cannot use it as a variable name. Change that to:

```
awk -F"," -v idx=2 '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ idx) print i}')
```

The field specifier, `$`, prefixing the `idx` is also not correct, you want to use the string as it is.

Comment: you know that i have just spent almost 2 hours trying to spot the problem? THX!

Comment: would you mind helping me with this last little thing? do you have any idea why awk cant find a match with my command? i have edited to find the col number if a match is founf, thx : key=$(echo "hello,there" | awk -F"," -v idx="hello" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ $idx) print i}')

Comment: remove the `$` from `idx`: `if ($i ~ idx)`